# Merging two columns to one with certain format

Tags: matlab, vector, multiple-columns

I have 2 column vectors of the form following form:
A = [650; 854; 956] and B = [756; 890; 1057].

The desired output would be a single column vector of the form:
C = [650 756 854 890 956 1057]

What would be the appropriate way to get the desired output (without any for loop)?

I thank for your time.

Best Regards!

Comment: If you want to concatenate and then sort the two arrays, you ca use [sort](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html): `C=sort([A ;B])'`

Comment: @il_raffa The given solution is very helpful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can basically just do this:

```
C = [A.'; B.'];
C = C(:);
```

The C will be a column vector with the desired values.

How this works is that we first concatenate the two transposed column vectors into two rows and then use the matlab `colon` operator to do interweave the values.

Comment: The solution is useful. Thank you very much.

Comment: on the first line you could also use the transpose operator once on the concatenated matrix: `C = [A,B].';`